# Identify this bicycle: Bianchi

Tags: identify-this-bike

I recently bought this Bianchi bicycle as my first re-build project. It's covered in a thin layer of rust but could really look amazing with help of a little elbow grease.

Managed to find a bicycle called the Bianchi L'Eroica which looks very similar, but admittedly this version could be a cheaper version as the seat and some elements do look much cheaper.

Does anyone know what bicycle this is or how I can find out?

Yehtsay

[image: Bianchi - Name this Bicycle!]

Comment: It's likely from the 1980s.  What else do you need to know?  The main markers are the crank (square-shank 3-piece) and the downtube shifters.

Comment: I'd start by putting the chain on properly, before it chips paint.  Remove the hefty padlock before it chips paint, and inflate the tyres to protect the rims from the ground.   Its a loverly looking bike btw - horizontal top tubes just look "right" to me.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

The padlock and other additions have been taken  off and I'm already working on it Needs quite a lot of attention, but that it will receive. Craggie - too right!

I'd like to know the exact model (within reason). It looks like the L'Eroica but it doesn't have the same quality components I'd expect. Especially for the price branded about for it. Perhaps another model?

Comment: I have a Bianchi Verata that looks a lot like that.  Does it have a marking for the tubing?  Like a sticker on the seat tube that says "Reynolds XXX(numbers)" or something?

Comment: Bianchi L'Eeroica is a new model made in the style of old bikes, it's not that one.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to be a 1973-1975 Bianchi 10 sp. I am able to choose the dates based off the logo used. To me it looks like a Special. However it seems you do not have a lot of the original parts, as this would have come with Campagnolo parts, and unless you are lucky,I am going to guess, those still aren't on this bike.

[image]

This is the 1973 Bianchi catalog. I choose the model over any other that look similar because of your "rack attachment" this is the only model sold in celeste that had a fender mount. I am also going to say it isnt 1973, because the fork crowns were all chrome in 73, so most likely a 1975, or you have a non original fork.

Comment: I will admit I cannot be 100% because of the lack of pictures, measurements, and more detailed info

Comment: It looks like the question contains some less racing model.  I think it has more space between the tyre and the seattube.